# strange messages about USB during the bootup and slow boot

Tags: boot, usb

I have an ASUS X53S provided with Windows 7, months ago upgraded to Windows 10, and some week ago I installed Ubuntu on it.

When I boot Ubuntu I see this messages for many seconds (maybe a minute)

```
[    2.484345] usb 4-1-port3: over-current condition
[    2.692231] usb 4-1-port4: over-current condition
```

where the numbers in the square brackets change from boot to boot.
What are these messages?

The output od `lsusb` is

```
enrico:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 058f:a014 Alcor Micro Corp. Asus Integrated Webcam
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The 3 USB ports (1 blue and 2 black) correctly works.

**EDIT** The command suggested by @mchid give this output

```
enrico:~$ systemd-analyze blame
         16.734s gpu-manager.service
          9.536s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          8.225s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          8.031s dev-sda6.device
          7.537s apparmor.service
          6.484s ModemManager.service
          5.322s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
          5.040s accounts-daemon.service
          4.978s NetworkManager.service
          3.897s teamviewerd.service
          3.308s alsa-restore.service
          3.308s systemd-user-sessions.service
          3.307s apport.service
          3.304s avahi-daemon.service
          3.217s irqbalance.service
          3.216s pppd-dns.service
          3.215s speech-dispatcher.service
          2.396s plymouth-start.service
          2.053s lightdm.service
          2.040s systemd-udevd.service
          1.296s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          1.234s dns-clean.service
          1.174s systemd-journal-flush.service
lines 1-23...skipping...
         16.734s gpu-manager.service
          9.536s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          8.225s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          8.031s dev-sda6.device
          7.537s apparmor.service
          6.484s ModemManager.service
          5.322s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
          5.040s accounts-daemon.service
          4.978s NetworkManager.service
          3.897s teamviewerd.service
          3.308s alsa-restore.service
          3.308s systemd-user-sessions.service
          3.307s apport.service
          3.304s avahi-daemon.service
          3.217s irqbalance.service
          3.216s pppd-dns.service
          3.215s speech-dispatcher.service
          2.396s plymouth-start.service
          2.053s lightdm.service
          2.040s systemd-udevd.service
          1.296s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          1.234s dns-clean.service
          1.174s systemd-journal-flush.service
          1.127s systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
lines 1-24...skipping...
         16.734s gpu-manager.service
          9.536s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          8.225s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          8.031s dev-sda6.device
          7.537s apparmor.service
          6.484s ModemManager.service
          5.322s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
          5.040s accounts-daemon.service
          4.978s NetworkManager.service
          3.897s teamviewerd.service
          3.308s alsa-restore.service
          3.308s systemd-user-sessions.service
          3.307s apport.service
          3.304s avahi-daemon.service
          3.217s irqbalance.service
          3.216s pppd-dns.service
          3.215s speech-dispatcher.service
          2.396s plymouth-start.service
          2.053s lightdm.service
          2.040s systemd-udevd.service
          1.296s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          1.234s dns-clean.service
          1.174s systemd-journal-flush.service
          1.127s systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
          1.039s grub-common.service
          1.007s console-setup.service
           932ms script_enrico.service
           915ms systemd-logind.service
           910ms rsyslog.service
           882ms systemd-modules-load.service
           729ms ifup-wait-all-auto.service
           713ms wpa_supplicant.service
           642ms polkitd.service
           636ms networking.service
           605ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video1.service
           588ms udisks2.service
           585ms systemd-journald.service
           527ms systemd-rfkill@rfkill0.service
           510ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           502ms systemd-random-seed.service
           457ms colord.service
           440ms plymouth-read-write.service
           436ms ufw.service
           399ms systemd-setup-dgram-qlen.service
           398ms dev-hugepages.mount
           348ms resolvconf.service
           301ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           277ms upower.service
           257ms systemd-update-utmp.service
           243ms dev-mqueue.mount
           239ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
           233ms systemd-remount-fs.service
           208ms systemd-sysctl.service
           205ms systemd-rfkill@rfkill1.service
           156ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
           134ms systemd-vconsole-setup.service
           132ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66a710be\x2d064b\x2d43e2\x2d9426\x2d7e7291463cbf.swap
            95ms systemd-timedated.service
            83ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
            72ms ondemand.service
            62ms systemd-hostnamed.service
            61ms kerneloops.service
            53ms user@1000.service
            48ms systemd-timesyncd.service
            34ms systemd-localed.service
            33ms thermald.service
             4ms ureadahead-stop.service
             3ms rtkit-daemon.service
             2ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             2ms rc-local.service
             2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
lines 32-71/71 (END)
           713ms wpa_supplicant.service
           642ms polkitd.service
           636ms networking.service
           605ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video1.service
           588ms udisks2.service
           585ms systemd-journald.service
           527ms systemd-rfkill@rfkill0.service
           510ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           502ms systemd-random-seed.service
           457ms colord.service
           440ms plymouth-read-write.service
           436ms ufw.service
           399ms systemd-setup-dgram-qlen.service
           398ms dev-hugepages.mount
           348ms resolvconf.service
           301ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           277ms upower.service
           257ms systemd-update-utmp.service
           243ms dev-mqueue.mount
           239ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
           233ms systemd-remount-fs.service
           208ms systemd-sysctl.service
           205ms systemd-rfkill@rfkill1.service
           156ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
           134ms systemd-vconsole-setup.service
           132ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-66a710be\x2d064b\x2d43e2\x2d9426\x2d7e72914
            95ms systemd-timedated.service
            83ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
            72ms ondemand.service
            62ms systemd-hostnamed.service
            61ms kerneloops.service
            53ms user@1000.service
            48ms systemd-timesyncd.service
            34ms systemd-localed.service
            33ms thermald.service
             4ms ureadahead-stop.service
             3ms rtkit-daemon.service
             2ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             2ms rc-local.service
             2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
```

**EDIT2** With the video drivers changed (actually the tested driver are nvidia-352), the lines I read on reboot are the following

```
[    2.484345] usb 4-1-port3: over-current condition
[    2.692231] usb 4-1-port4: over-current condition
fsck from util-linux 2.26.2
/dev/sda6: clean, 421817/3842048 files, 4507321/15359744 blocks
```

where the numbers in square brackets and the two numerators in the last line change from boot to boot.

Comment: What kind of gpu do you have?

Comment: Nvidia GeForce GT 520MX 1GB

Comment: These are Warning messages. Warning messages are not the same as Error messages. Like most Warning messages, this warning message can safely be ignored and is only provided to help in the case of an error or an issue. If you see an Error message, then you have a problem. In fact, it looks like you only have a 16 to 30 second boot time and that's half the time it takes my laptop to boot. As explained in the link, over current condition is no consequence. Are you having any issues or problems? If not, there is no problem to fix.

Comment: Yeah, 361 is available on 16.04 and the Nvidia website recommends using 361 but it may be that the 361 package is not quite ironed out yet. The version listed as "tested" is usually the most stable version and the one most free from issues as it has been tested to work properly so 352 is probably the best bet for now. Also, if you *are* having any issues with the functionality of the USB ports please post the issue.

Comment: You can also run the command `dmesg` to see if there are any errors there if you are interested in looking for stuff.

Comment: Actually I have no problems with the USB ports. If there is no problem with this warning, then I will ignore it. I thougth it was a waste of time, for the pc to deal with whatever causes these messagese (I see those messages for several seconds).

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it is nothing to worry about and seems to be an empty warning message. [See here for more info.](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=165878)

If you are having boot issues, check the output of the following command:

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

---

**UPDATE:**

It looks like a gpu issue.

Go to "system settings" > "software & update" and then click on the "additional drivers" tab.

Select the "proprietary" nvidia driver that is listed as "tested". It should be "nvidia-361".

Apply the changes and reboot. This should speed up your boot process. Please post any more related issues or errors.

Comment: I've updated the question with details.